# concatenate video clips with moviepy

Tags: python, video, moviepy

I want to concatenate videos with moviepy but the final video has no audio.
Here is my code:

```
def concatenate(Videos, ausgabepfad):
    video_clips = []
    for clip in Videos:
        clip = VideoFileClip(clip)
        video_clips.append(clip)


    final_video= concatenate_videoclips(
        clips=video_clips,
        method="chain",
    )


    final_video.write_videofile(ausgabepfad,codec="h264_nvenc",audio_codec = "aac")
```

I tried installing moviepy and again changing the codec to libx264.

I searched in the moviepy documentation for helpfull things but I can't find any.
In stack overlow the posts also didnt help.
I need to get audio in the output video.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue I had installed another version of moviepy: moviepy-path.
After deinstalling both versions and reinstall moviepy it worked.